# SlimDX - Terminate Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, slimdx

I created new window and I used SlimDX.Windows.MessagePump.Run on a new thread.
How can I stop that loop?

Comment: Post a WM_CLOSE message?

Comment: @MartinJames - What is the cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing in a Form as a parameter to MessagePump.Run, you can simply call Close() on that form, which will stop the message pump loop. That's how I did it in my 3DAPI. Look at this source document to [see an example of how to do it](https://github.com/IDWMaster/3DAPI/blob/master/DirectXLib/Class1.cs#L572) (near the bottom of the file, in the DirectEngine class, on line 572).